# jquery drop down mobile menu link not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

my drop down menu link item are not clickable, whenever i click on them the menu just close back to original position and nothing change.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/g6jjL/1/ here is my fiddle

EDIT: it should close, but sending me to the link i clicked.

Comment: You actually getting what you have in your JS part? What is the expected result?

Comment: It's working fine. You commanded it to close and its closing. What's your expectations from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of your drop down is working as it is written in your JS

Change your code to this and your drop down will only slideToggle when you click the "menu" word.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#nav-mobile > a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

In case this behaviour is OK then you should consider you are overwritting the behaviour of your anchor tags.

Add this to your code and you will be redirected to the link you want.

```
$('#nav-mobile ul li a').click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: it should close, but send me to the link

Comment: omg thank you, i am pretty new to js and i didn't catch that, this means, only slide toggle when the 1st child of the id is pressed right?

Comment: See the update to get the redirection of your anchor tags that may not be working well.

Comment: Yes, in the first case you should keep en mind that the element #nav-mobile wraps the hole thing, so if you click whevever inside the black box you will slideToggle the menu. With the first answer I have you correct that, and with the second you get the redirection of your anchor tags that the behaviour of your menu was preventing it to work well.